# What does `twoside` mean here?

Tags: formatting, templates, double-sided

I am writing a novel (A5 size). This is the code I am using.

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
normalheadings,twoside=true]{scrbook}
```

What does `twoside` mean here?

Comment: It means the document will have (possibly different) left and right pages, like in a book, to be printed on both sides of the paper.

Answer (score 6):

The option `twoside` means that the document will have (possibly different) left and right pages, like in a book, to be printed on both sides of the paper.

The complementary option is `oneside`, which means a document with (usually) a right-side page only.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @egreg!